# Can't Delete My Temporary Pointers?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having an issue with deleting pointers. I don't think I'm doing anything compiler illegal or anything, but perhaps I am, so I would appreciate it if someone could explain the flaw in my logic. I'm hoping the below function should be enough to help, as the whole thing would be a lot to transcribe, but if any more of the code is required, please let me know and I'll add it!

The below is a function to remove lockers from a linked list I've created. I've done my best to cover every conceivable case. The problem arises when I try to actually deallocate the memory of a locker I want to delete. The lines where I've tried to delete the temp variable that references that locked are commented out, because the code breaks with them included. Obviously, though, without them, I can't delete the lockers like I want.

```
int SelfStorageList::removeLockersOverdue() {

int lockersDeleted = 0;

if (isEmpty()) {
    return 0;
}

if (head->objLocker.isRentOverdue && head==tail) { //If that was the only locker, the tail needs to be updated to = head = 0
    delete head;  
    head = tail = 0;
    return ++lockersDeleted;
}

LockerNode *prev = head;
LockerNode *curr = head->next;

while (curr != 0) {

    if((curr == tail) && curr->objLocker.isRentOverdue) { //If the current locker is tail and needs deleting
        LockerNode *temp = curr;
        curr = prev;
        //delete temp;
        lockersDeleted++;
    }


    if(prev->objLocker.isRentOverdue) { //General case: Previous locker needs deleting
       LockerNode *temp = prev;
       prev = prev->next;
       curr = curr->next;
       //delete temp;
       lockersDeleted++;

   }

  else { //Update the pointers if not updated anywhere else

  prev = prev->next; 
  curr = curr->next;

  }

}

return lockersDeleted;

}
```

Any "pointers"? (Terrible pun. :p )

Comment: What are the actual errors/behavior you're getting? "Code breaks" doesn't really help.

Comment: I'd help more if I could, but I don't really get a descriptive error message. The code hangs up in the heap at a line that says  _ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));

Comment: Are you sure `tail` is maintained?  Instead of checking `if(curr==tail)` why don't you check `if(curr->next != 0)`?

Comment: Quick question.  What is the purpose of this code?  Is this an assignment?  Is this fooling around to learn something?  Or is this supposed to be actual production code?  If it's the 3rd, look into using a `std::list` and also getting some CS courses under your belt.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through this with a debugger? If so, at which line of your code does the assertion appear? If not, it'll be difficult for anyone to help you with the information you have provided. Also, if you could make the code a self-contained complete example that can actually be compiled and run, then that would help you find the problem and (if you can't) it will help us find the problem with you.

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity Sort of both 1 and 2? I am an undergrad, but this is a project for my own understanding/personal purposes. With regards to the debugger, I have, setting some break points and tracing where I think it might be fooling up, but it goes into and stays into the heap for so long, it's somewhat impractical. I've tried stepping over those bits, but I can't seem to pinpoint it. I'll try to debug it again though, and see if I can actually find the specific line of issue in my own code. It would be difficult to self-contain with all the dependencies, but I can try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're maintaining a singly-linked list, I see you're keeping track of a `prev` pointer as you're iterating through your list.  That's as it should be, of course, since you can't get the previous node of a given node in a linked list if it's singly-linked without remembering what its previous node was.  Your problem is simply that your logic is busted:  If a deletion is needed, you need to be deleting the `curr` node, and patching up the `prev` node to point its `next` pointer to `curr->next` before you `delete curr`.

Think about it:  What you're doing is deleting the `prev` node, but there's likely a "more previous than that" node that's still pointing to the `prev` node that you just deleted.  The next time you iterate through the list, you'll be iterating into formerly allocated nodes, which may be allocated for some entirely different purpose by that point.  Your memory allocator is failing some internal assertion because likely on the next time you call removeLockersOverdue(), the memory has NOT yet been allocated to something else, and you're still finding the same node there that you already deleted, and finding again that it's overdue, and deleting it again, and your memory allocator is complaining that you're deleting memory that isn't allocated.  (It would be really nice if it gave you that clear of a message, wouldn't it!)

Also, your special case stuff for handling the very first node & last node can be simplified & commonized; I'll avoid rewriting it for you so you can see if you can simplify it yourself.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation! I think I can rework my solution based on yours and @Casey's advice. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
while (curr != 0) {
    if((curr == tail) && curr->objLocker.isRentOverdue) {
        LockerNode *temp = curr;
        curr = prev;
        //delete temp;
        lockersDeleted++;
    }
```

You are not updating the previous node's next pointer here, so it ends up dangling (pointing to memory that is deleted). You also leave `tail` pointing at the deleted node.

```
    if(prev->objLocker.isRentOverdue) {
       LockerNode *temp = prev;
       prev = prev->next;
       curr = curr->next;
       //delete temp;
       lockersDeleted++;

   }
```

Again, you don't update the `next` pointer in the list that points at the deleted node.

```
  else { //Update the pointers if not updated anywhere else

  prev = prev->next; 
  curr = curr->next;

  }
}
```

I think you are greatly confusing yourself by carrying around two pointers in the loop. Try to write it again with just a single pointer tracking the node you are currently examining, and draw some pictures of the three possible cases (remove first node, remove last node, remove internal node) to ensure you are getting the removal logic right.

Comment: @phonetagger Liar! Only 23 seconds.

Comment: Haha, thanks to both of you! You're right that keeping track of all the pointers confused me a bit - I was trying to follow it with paper illustrations of the lists though, as suggested. I see your point in that one might be easier to manage, but somehow I thought two would improve readability. I'll have a look to see if I can implement it with one. Thanks again!